# Crash on call from boost::python::exec( anything )

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python, python-3.3

I'm trying to implement some Python stuff into my program and I've decided to use Boost::Python, so I compiled it according to the instructions, with bjam, using mingw/gcc, getting dlls and .a files
I'm using Code::Blocks for this, so I've put the dlls in the working directory of my project, where the rest of dlls I use are, and decided to run `boost::python::exec("b = 5");`
Instantly I get a crash. Ideas?

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

float func(int a)
{
  return a*a-0.5;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test_module)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  def("func", func);
}

int main()
{
  //Try one
  boost::python::exec("b = 5");
  //Crash

  //Try two
  Py_Initialize();
  boost::python::exec("b = 5");
  //Works fine

  //Try three
  Py_Initialize();
  boost::python::exec("import test_module");
  //Throws boost::python::error_already_set and crashes

  /*
    Something along the lines of
    boost::python::exec("import test_module\n"
                        "var = test_module.func( 3 )\n");
  */    
}
```

Under the build options section of my project, I've added `libboost_python3-mgw48-d-1_54.dll` and `libpython33` to be linked so it'd compile.
Ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this more or preferable provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?  Where are you trying to invoke `boost::python::exec()`?

Comment: @TannerSansbury in int main(). It's literally the first line in it, the program crashes instantly in that point

Comment: When embedding Python, the interpreter needs initialized ([`Py_Initialize()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/init.html#Py_Initialize)) before making calls to Boost.Python.  Could you provide the minimal C++ code, and your overall goal?  It is not clear to as to what is being attempted.  Are you trying to embed Python?  What is the relevance of `test_module` extension?

Comment: @TannerSansbury I know, I've noticed that while trying to use the C API for Python, which I failed at. I'm trying to embed Python and to allow it to use the function above, that's why I've exposed it according to boost's tutorial on it. Allow me to use a pastebin to not to clutter this page, please take a look at http://pastebin.com/FHPmry9u

Comment: An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) is not always clutter.  When trying to debug code, it may become necessary.  The original posted question did not mention a few critical details that would have made answering very difficult.  If desired, feel free to revert the edit, but the complete problem avoids link rot and may be helpful to future users.

Answer (score 1):

When embedding Python, almost all calls to Python or Boost.Python should occur after the interpreter has been initialized with [`Py_Initialize()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/init.html#Py_Initialize).  Trying to invoke the interpreter before initialization, such as with `boost::python::exec()`, will result in undefined behavior.

While that identifies the source of the crash, there are some subtle details to obtain the accomplish the final goal of embedding Python and a module, then have `exec` import the embedded module.

- When importing a module, Python will first check if the module is a built-in module.  If the module is not a built-in module, then Python will try to load a library based on the module name, and expects the library to provide a function that will initialize the module.  As the `test_module` is being embedded, its initialization needs to be explicitly added so that `import` can find it when searching for built-in modules.
- The `import` statement uses the `__import__` function.  This function needs to be available within `exec`'s globals.

Here is a complete example demonstrating how to accomplish this:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

float func(int a)
{
  return a*a-0.5;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test_module)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  def("func", func);
}

// Use macros to account for changes in Python 2 and 3:
// - Python's C API for embedding requires different naming conventions for
//   module initialization functions.
// - The builtins module was renamed.
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
#  define MODULE_INIT_FN(name) BOOST_PP_CAT(PyInit_, name)
#  define PYTHON_BUILTINS "builtins"
#else
#  define MODULE_INIT_FN(name) BOOST_PP_CAT(init, name)
#  define PYTHON_BUILTINS "__builtin__"
#endif

int main()
{
  // Add the test_module module to the list of built-in modules.  This
  // allows it to be imported with 'import test_module'.
  PyImport_AppendInittab("test_module", &MODULE_INIT_FN(test_module));

  Py_Initialize();

  namespace python = boost::python;
  try
  {
    // Create an empty dictionary that will function as a namespace.
    python::dict ns;

    // The 'import' statement depends on the __import__ function.  Thus,
    // to enable 'import' to function the context of 'exec', the builtins
    // module needs to be within the namespace being used.
    ns["__builtins__"] = python::import(PYTHON_BUILTINS);

    // Execute code.  Modifications to variables will be reflected in
    // the ns.
    python::exec("b = 5", ns);

    std::cout << "b is " << python::extract<int>(ns["b"]) << std::endl;

    // Execute code using the built-in test_module.
    python::exec(
      "import test_module\n"
      "var = test_module.func(b)\n",
      ns);

    std::cout << "var is " << python::extract<float>(ns["var"]) << std::endl;
  }
  catch (python::error_already_set&)
  {
    PyErr_Print();
  }
}
```

When executed, its output is:

```
b is 5
var is 24.5
```

Comment: "ImportError: No module named '__builtin__'". Uh.

Comment: @P.K.: Doh, looks like I built against Python 2.  Per the [porting guide](http://docs.pythonsprints.com/python3_porting/py-porting.html#name-changes), the `__builtin__` module was renamed to `builtins` in Python 3.  I will try to find some time to rebuild against Python 3 and verify the change.

Comment: Oh. Well, I've changed that around, but now there's an importerror. `Line 1, <string>, ___import___ not found`

Comment: @P.K.: Odd.  I changed the import (reflected in the above code) and it worked with Python 3.3.2.