# Calling some PyObject functions causes segfault - Boost python

Tags: c++, python-3.x, opencv, boost

For a project, I need to interface some C++ modules in Python. To do so, I need a converter which converts a Python tuple to a cv::Size (openCV object). Here is my C++ function :

```
cv::Size tupleToSize(PyObject* obj)
{
    // Check if obj is a tuple :
    if (!PyTuple_CheckExact(obj))
        return cv::Size(-1,-1);

    // Element Extraction :
    PyObject* x = PyTuple_GetItem(obj,0);
    PyObject* y = PyTuple_GetItem(obj,1);

    // TODO : extract values from x and y
    // Trying to create two variables a et b that contains the values
    long a = PyLong_AsLong(x);
    long b = PyLong_AsLong(y);
    /* The first line causes a SegFault*/

    // New cv::Size with extracted values :
    cv::Size ret(a,b);
    return ret;
}
```

And here is the main that calls my function :

```
int main()
{

    // New cv:Size :
    Size s(10,20);
    // Conversion :
    PyObject* ss = SizeToTuple(s); // I have a SizeToTuple function that works fine.
    // Reconversion :
    Size sss = tupleToSize(ss); /* SEGFAULT */


    return 0;

}
```

So, I wonder if my PyObject x and y are not of type Long, so I decided to check their type but when I call some functions as :

```
PyObject_repr(x);
PyObject_str(x);
```

They also cause a segfault.

So, I'm pretty stuck. Do you have any suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Python interpreter should be initialized before making most of those calls.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19816546/1053968) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tanner Sansburry, I solved the problem by just adding :

```
Py_Initialize();
```

in my code.

Problem solved !